# Attempting to join a SQL Server table with a singular reference to a table with multiple references

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query I'm creating where I have the total of all receivers from last year, all products we returned and the reason. The problem I'm having is figuring out how to properly join the table with the total receivers from each customer and the table with the list of issues.

When I do the join I end up with the sum from the receivers table repeating. I understand why this is happening I just don't know how to fix it.

FirstCTE

```
Receiver Qty     fvendno
---------------------------
   21             ACO   
    2             AEG   
   16             AER   
  139             AET
```

SecondCTE

```
fdincidate    Fkey_ID   fcvendno    FPROBLEM
-----------------------------------------------------
3/8/16 9:57     2451    AET     Wrong Quantity      
3/8/16 9:59     2452    AET     Wrong Quantity      
4/18/16 10:41   2527    AET     Wrong Quantity      
4/28/16 11:57   2540    AET     Defective Material  
6/24/16 14:19   2595    AET     Wrong Material      
11/2/16 10:51   2700    AET     Wrong Material      
12/1/16 12:29   2804    AET     Wrong Material      
1/9/17 14:40    2838    AET     Wrong Material      
1/18/05 16:02   122     AIN                         
11/4/15 11:52   2316    ALF     Wrong Quantity      
6/2/14 10:58    1565    AVL     Wrong Quantity      
6/2/14 12:24    1567    AVL     Defective Material
```

Query:

```
SELECT        
    ap.fcompany, 
    FC.[Receiver Qty], 
    COUNT(SC.FKey_ID) AS 'Number of issues per vendor',
    CASE sc.FPROBLEM 
       WHEN 'Wrong Quantity' 
          THEN 'Shortage' 
       WHEN 'Defective Material' 
          THEN 'Defective Material' 
       WHEN 'Wrong Material' 
          THEN 'Wrong Material' 
    END AS fproblem
FROM            
    SecondCTE AS SC 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    FirstCTE AS FC ON FC.fvendno = SC.fcvendno 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    apvend AS ap ON SC.fcvendno = ap.fvendno
WHERE 
    (SC.fdincidate BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) 
                       AND DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) -1, -1))
GROUP BY 
    FC.[Receiver Qty], ap.fcompany, SC.FPROBLEM
ORDER BY 
    ap.fcompany, SC.FPROBLEM
```

The result I want

```
fcompany  Receiver Qty  Number oF issues per vendor  fProblem
A           139            1                         Defective Material
A                          3                         Wrong Material
A                          3                         Shortage
B           597            2                         Defective Material
B                          2                         Wrong Material
C           16             3                         Shortage
D           13             3                         Shortage
E           400            25                        Shortage
F           10             1                         Defective Material
G           90             1                         Shortage
```

The result I get

```
fcompany  Receiver Qty  Number or issues per vendor   fProblem
---------------------------------------------------------------
A           139                 1                     Defective Material
A           139                 3                     Wrong Material
A           139                 3                     Shortage
B           597                 2                     Defective Material
B           597                 2                     Wrong Material
C           16                  3                     Shortage
D           13                  3                     Shortage
E           400                 25                    Shortage
F           10                  1                     Defective Material
G           90                  1                     Shortage
```

Comment: This must be accomplished in your reporting application. Try to order by Fcompany and Receiver when receiver = ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using  **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)** to set repeating instances of `[Reciver Qty]` to null:

```
, thirdcte as (
    select
        ap.fcompany
      , fc.[Reciver Qty]
      , [Number of issues per vendor] = count(sc.fkey_id) 
      , fproblem = case sc.fproblem when 'Wrong Quantity' then 'Shortage' 
                         when 'Defective Material' then 'Defective Material' 
                         when 'Wrong Material' then 'Wrong Material' 
                         end 
      , rn = row_number() over (
           partition by ap.fcompany 
           order by (case sc.fproblem when 'Wrong Quantity' then 'Shortage' 
           when 'Defective Material' then 'Defective Material' 
           when 'Wrong Material' then 'Wrong Material' 
           end)
        )
     from Secondcte as sc 
      left outer join Firstcte as fc on fc.fvendno = sc.fcvendno 
      left outer join apvend as ap on sc.fcvendno = ap.fvendno
     where (sc.fdincidate between dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, getdate()) - 1, 0) 
            and dateadd(month, datediff(month, - 1, getdate()) - 1, - 1))
     group by fc.[Reciver Qty]
        , ap.fcompany
        , sc.fproblem
)

select 
      fcompany
    , [Reciver Qty] = case when rn = 1 then [Reciver Qty] else null end
    , [Number of issues per vendor]
    ,  fproblem
  from thirdcte
  order by fcompany, fproblem
```

Note: Be careful with **`between`** [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand - 2009-10-16](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you want to empty `Reciver` when the previous record already has the same value. You could use the `LAG()`-function:

```
WITH result AS (

    SELECT        ap.fcompany, FC.[Reciver Qty], COUNT(SC.FKey_ID) AS 'Number of issues per vendor'
    , CASE sc.FPROBLEM WHEN 'Wrong Quantity' THEN 'Shortage' 
                       WHEN 'Defective Material' THEN 'Defective Material' 
                       WHEN 'Wrong Material' THEN 'Wrong Material' 
                       END AS fproblem
     FROM            SecondCTE AS SC left OUTER JOIN FirstCTE AS FC 
                              ON FC.fvendno = SC.fcvendno LEFT OUTER JOIN
                              apvend AS ap 
                              ON SC.fcvendno = ap.fvendno
     WHERE (SC.fdincidate BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) AND DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, - 1, GETDATE()) - 1, - 1))
     GROUP BY FC.[Reciver Qty]
     , ap.fcompany
     , SC.FPROBLEM
)

SELECT fcompany
, ISNULL(NULLIF(Reciver, LAG(Reciver,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY fcompany, FPROBLEM)),'') AS Reciver
, [Qty Number of issues per vendor]
, fProblem
from result
 ORDER BY fcompany
 , FPROBLEM
```

Comment: Wouldn't that null out a valid `[Reciver Qty]` if a different but sequential `fcompany` had the same `[Reciver Qty]` as the previous row? If you use `over (partition by fcompany order by fproblem)` that should take care of that possibility.